# Best way to use Windows Bluetooth keyboard with a Mac but retain the similar Windows shortcuts?

Tags: windows, macos

Long time Windows user, and prefer it because of the shortcuts.

Recently joined a company that uses Macbook Pro as their default laptop.
Therefore, would like to use my Windows Bluetooth Keyboard with the Macbook Pro.

What is the best way to use my Windows Bluetooth keyboard with it but retain the shortcuts that are similar to Windows (Alt Tab, Ctrl Pg Up, Ctrl Pg Down) etc. I basically want to switch the keys on my Mac so that they essentially mirror the Windows keyboard layout so that I can use similar keyboard shortcuts for both platforms (personal Windows device and work Mac device, not at the same time obviously).

For example, I think switching the Control and Command keys would mirror the Alt and Control keys. Please let me know if you have any suggestions/guides/best practices!